# .NET SIMD adding byte and ushort array

Tags: .net, vectorization, sse, simd, managed

There is a long byte array which needs to be added to the destination array of type short. The solution can be found here:
[SEE byte + short.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637214/sse-instructions-byteshort)
I am trying to do this using [managed SIMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors) 
which lacks the support of "unpack" instruction (*needed for unpacking single 16-element byte array to two 8-element short arrays for addition*).
Here are the supported operations by managed SIMD:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how the addition of two arrays (short[] = byte[] + short[]) can be achieved using the reduced SIMD instruction set above (avoiding scalar addition) ?

Answer (score 0):

The following [API proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/15957) will add the narrowing and widening operations. The proposed API follows a similar design as the underlying SSE2 instructions; to widen, the lower and upper halves of the input vector will be written to two output vectors. To narrow, elements coming from two input vectors are converted (with signed or unsigned saturation) and then packed into a single output vector.

Being an API proposal, it might take a long time to actually ship, or it might take forever.

These methods are useless (performance-wise) unless the JIT is finally upgraded to generate intrinsics. This, I'm afraid, means that you should simply assume the capability isn't there yet. If you currently uses a native code approach (via C++/CLI or P/Invoke), you should continue to use your current approach, since the alternative doesn't exist yet.

To find out the status of the JIT-side implementation: [Add JIT intrinsics support for vector conversion on AMD64 and x86 #10662](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/10662)

Based on the comments, it will not be in .NET Standard 2.0, but it is likely to be part of .NET Standard 2.1.